# PASCAL Error: Until expected but end found

Tags: pascal

I have problems with my pascal code.

When compiling it shows me the error: syntax : until expected but end found.

```
PROGRAM EvilGOTO;
Var rand,count,guess : integer;
LABEL correct, schleife, wrong, ende;

begin
    Randomize;
            count :=0;
            repeat
                    schleife:
                    count := count+1;
                    rand := Random(10);
                    guess := Random(10);
                    if rand=guess
                    then
                            writeln('Correct')
                            end
                    else
                            writeln('False Guess')
                            goto schleife
             until
             count = 10;
end.
```

can you help me?

Comment: `if..then..end` is the problem. That `end` after `writeln('Correct')`.

Comment: Best to avoid `goto`. Try to come up with another way to exit the loop on that else.

Comment: A side note: you seem to be using the `goto` to create a loop, but you are using it *inside* a loop (`repeat ... until`). That's perfectly superfluous and, when you've fixed the issue mentioned by @TLama, you can try and get rid of the `goto` (as well as the corresponding label).

Comment: can you pls help me to optimize this code?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PROGRAM EvilGOTO;
Var rand,count,guess : integer;
begin
    Randomize;
    count :=0;
    repeat
      rand := Random(10);
      guess := Random(10);
      if rand=guess then
         writeln('Correct')
         else
         begin
           count := count+1;
           writeln('False Guess');
         end
    until count = 10 or rand=guess;
end.
```

Comment: ok thank you very much, but the prog has to stop after a "correct" how can i get this function?

Comment: Now it stops after 10 "correct" values. Do you want to stop after first one?

Comment: the program should not show more than 10 false values and if one is correct it has to stop/end.

Comment: @Can I could not guess about that looking on your code :) Changed.

Comment: but now he gets boolean, but expects int64 :D

Comment: @Can `until (count = 10) or (rand=guess);`